# Difference Between Free and Paid magento Layered Navigation

Tags: magento

Can any one help me for Difference Between Free and Paid magento Layered Navigation Magento Extension.. I have both of the link of free and paid magneto extension..

- [Free](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html)
- [Paid](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gomage-advanced-navigation-v-4-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hello there are lot of differences... You can check it there itself.. In paid extension the layered navigation is totally different.. The below one is the image for paid extension. Where as you can see more new functionalities, but you cant find these functions in free extension

[image]

**Free Extension:**

[image]

what else the differences you need...

Answer (score 0):

Paid extensions have more control from admin panel as compared to free extensions.

and Paid extensions extensions provide more features.